# Very simple apache CXF - spring boot JAX-RS app

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, cxf

I am trying to get information about spring-boot with apache CXF rest application.

I have read on CXF website on how to spin it up but its documentation is very confusing and not really helpful.
(http://cxf.apache.org/docs/springboot.html)

I have tried to check out different github repos trying to spin up an restful api with spring-boot and CXF, but they are way to heavy with swagger implementations or docker implementations etc and I don't want that, its just confusing.

Or they are old versions of CXF.

So, can someone please show me a repo or just an simple explanation on how to spin up this, preferably with annotations and no configs.

Thank you.

Comment: You should probably look at the apache cxf user guide.

Comment: i have written that its documentation is huge and confusing. Not helpfull.

Comment: Sure, but ten pages into the document is the example you're looking for.

Comment: Again, not helpfull. please remove your comments.

Comment: Flagged to close

Answer (score 0):

You can find multiple samples here: https://github.com/apache/cxf/tree/master/distribution/src/main/release/samples/jax_rs

Comment: Can you show me the easy sample without swagger/docker etc?
As i told in my post, i have tried theese.

Comment: Well the simplest minimal version is to add the following to application.yml:
    cxf:
      jaxrs:
        component-scan: true
  
Your JAX-RS resources will be scanned automatically from Spring beans in this case.

Comment: The annotation @SpringBootApplication does a componentscan (Rest api is under Springbootapplication package).
So there should not be needed a config for doing the same thing. 
If i understand it correct.

Am i missing something when you say i need an YML file aswell? or are you complicating things?

Comment: The config in application.yml is needed to tell cxf to pickup the JAX-RS resources from the Spring components.

Comment: I added an application.properties file under the resources folder.
With the content: 
cxf.path=/services/hello
cxf.jaxrs.component-scan="true"

But its still not picking up the JAX-RS endpoint:
`code`
@Service
@Path("/hi")
public class RestApi {

    public RestApi(){}

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public Response.ResponseBuilder helloAPI(){
        return Response.ok("WOWO YEYE");
    }
}

`code`

Comment: Could you please share a sample project (e.g. on GitHub)?

Comment: Instead of ="true" write =true (it's boolean, not String), your resource method should not return Response.ResponseBuilder but Response or String, so add .build(). Moreover latest CXF release is 3.2.7, please use the latest version.

Comment: Thanks, Updated the gitrepo with fixes you said.
But still not working:
'rg.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jaxRsServer' defined in class path resource [org/apache/cxf/jaxrs/spring/SpringComponentScanServer.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; '

Comment: It's working great. Are you using JDK 8? Please share the full stacktrace.

Comment: java version "1.8.0_181"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_181-b13)

Its to long to send full stacktrace here. Can i send it in private chat? and when its solved we update this thread.

Comment: Feel free to send it to our user mailinglist: users@cxf.apache.org - see http://cxf.apache.org/mailing-lists.html how to subscribe

Comment: Did send a mail now.

Comment: I posted the whole question there, most likely wrong by me :D but its there anyways.

Comment: Haven't received anything: https://lists.apache.org/list.html?users@cxf.apache.org

Answer (score 0):

I have added an git Repo for this. A very easy one.

Its not working. Please comment on why springboot wont scan the API.

https://github.com/hannehanen/NotWorkingCFXSpringBootRS

Comment: This repo apparently works for some people. So the code itself is not wrong.
But for some reason i cant run it succesfully. Sadly. If it had something to do with my JRE or something else i dont know. (both trying on JRE 11 and JRE 8).

Answer (score -1):

Please, check me Repo https://github.com/EvgeniyLis/RestCxf
Probably, it is you are looking for. It is the simple Spring Boot JAX-RS app using Apache-cxf (without swagger implementations or docker implementations).